# if i have a pole in (0,0i), is the system stable for k=0?

Tags: control, control-system

KGH(s)=k/s(s^2+4s+7)

Is my system stable for k=0 ?
If i have a pole in 0,0i does it automatic says that my system is not stable

[image: root locus]

Answer (score 1):

An open loop pole at s=0 does not, generally, render a closed loop system unstable. Many systems have an open loop pole at s=0; for example, a PID controller places a pole there. For the coefficient values given, the closed loop will be stable for k<28.

BTW, your root locus does not represent the TF given in the question.

Comment: You right, its was only an example.

Comment: For future reference, there is no point in showing a diagram that you've copied from somewhere and has nothing to do with the question.